# impact of Windows Eventcreate.exe eventsource 'keywords'

Tags: event-log

When trying to register some new event log sources which are used by our applications I've noticed errors when registering events where the event source contains certain keywords.

```
ERROR: Source parameter is used to identify custom application/scripts only (not built-in sources).
```

II've noticed this when trying to use a /SO parameter containing the words 'Framework' or 'Application' (there may be others)

for example:

```
eventcreate /SO "Common Framework " /T Information /ID 5 /L APPLICATION /D "description"
```

produces the error message

I can't find any documentation for this and I'm wondering what the impact is,
If I use events containing those keywords will it allow me to write to the event log successfully (from experimenting that does seem to be the case), are there any side effects of using the events this way.

It strikes me that If I  use one of those keywords in all my events I can skip having to register events using an administrator account.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912118/redirect-sql-servers-events-from-std-application-log-into-a-custom-one