# Redirect SQL Server's events from std Application log into a custom one

Tags: sql-server, windows, registry

Had to seep through loads of info trying to restore the sequence of events that led to a crash yesterday, and got really interested in finding a solution to offload events from SQL Server to a custom event log.  Google yields only a [single promising result](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1034488-1550-1.aspx), with the link to [a guide on creating custom event logs](http://www.jasonsamuel.com/2010/01/08/creating-a-custom-event-log-under-event-viewer-to-log-server-events/)..

While i wouldn't go that far as to call SQL events [pointless](http://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/sql-servers-utterly-pointless-event-logging/) (though agreed, 17101 and 17103 spelling out "*(c) 20?? Microsoft Corporation*" and "*All rights reserved.*" upon each restart are a definite waste!),
**IMHO it would certainly be useful and beneficial to re-route SQL events to its own log!**
Hell, even IE has got one, built-in!  *Why can't SQL Server take that as a better practice to implement?*  Especially on Vista/Win7, which provide tons of individual logs for loads of other apps - quite useless IMHO (never had any need to dig in there), but forcing UI to slow to a crawl each time you open it:

[image: Snapshot of Event Log view in MMC on Win7]

I successfully follow the guidelines of creating a 'SQLServer' custom log, add the source definitions to it.  Unfortunately, any attempts to re-route SQL events to it seem to bump into an issue of MSSQLSERVER (the log source matching the default name for the SQL service) being some kind of a *built-in* source:

> EventCreate /l "SQLServer" /t Information /so MSSQLSERVER /id 1 /d "Log created"
>   ERROR: Source parameter is used to identify custom application/scripts only (not built-in sources).

When i mark MSSQLSERVER under my log as CustomSource (DWORD=1), the error above disappears:

> EventCreate /l "SQLServer" /t Information /so MSSQLSERVER /id 2 /d "New entry"
>   SUCCESS: A 'information' type event is created in the 'MSSQLSERVER' log/source.

and indeed an event with ID=2, desc='New entry' is added to the custom event log!  **However, in this configuration the real MSSQLSERVER service does not write events to either this new log or to the standard 'Application' log :(.** Functionality is restored upon reverting log definitions in registry (no reboots needed!), so it is a reversible scenario.

Also, from the above it looks as *any source can only be associated with a single log*..  Logical enough.  But what defines these *built-in* sources then, if i remove the explicit registry entries?  Maybe I should've restarted the machine after making these changes (though that was not necessary to revert back)?

Has anybody explored this further and maybe had any success?

**EDIT**: So far, like i said, there seems to be the only way to deal with this by filtering out MSSQLSERVER (or other SQL service name) events from view, like so:

[image: Filter out MSSQLSERVER events]

But the XML tab exposes what goes under the hood, and it's quite ugly (as in *extremely inefficient*):

[image: Query that's being processed for such filter]

I want a better way to manage this event data, and am sure i'm not the only one.
So if any folks at Microsoft are reading this - take note!

Comment: I don't think you can. Some API's let you write logs based purely on source, others let you specify both event source and the log you're targeting. Probably, when you *have* switched the MSSQLSERVER source to an alternate log, these type of calls will be failing. Stick with filtering the log (or viewing the SQL logs through SSMS).

Comment: Looks that way unfortunately.  Point is:  SQL Server floods the App log, and it becomes extra clumsy and slow to find other events (it's not SQL's events i'm after..)

Answer (score 1):

[ERRORLOG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885.aspx)?

Comment: Not quite.  Same info is written to the `Windows Application Eventlog`.  I would rather designate an explicit custom `Windows` eventlog and let SQL persist its events there, otherwise it floods the standard one:  80..90% of it is SQL stuff.  It could be filtered out, but that most probably would need to be set every time one opens Event Viewer..

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create an event viewer filter to exclude a particular source, here is the XML (Suppressing SQL Express events from the 'Application' log).

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*
    </Select>
    <Suppress Path="Application">*[System[Provider[@Name='MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS']]]</Suppress>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

See [Event Selection on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385231.aspx)